# useState hook updating without using the set method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

I am trying to update an array of object which contain my checkbox data. I need to update the value field when user clicks the checkbox. I think I can achieve this by using a mapping through the array and then using the spread operator to update the state.

My doubt is **why the state is updating when using a find method?** I thought only set method can update the state. Sorry in advance if this is an obvious noobie mistake.

```js
let checkBoxDataTemp = [
  {
    name: "spam",
    value: false,
  },
  {
    name: "dangerousProduct",
    value: false,
  },
  {
    name: "sexuallyExplicit",
    value: false,
  },
  {
    name: "other",
    value: false,
  },
];

const [checkBoxData, setCheckBoxData] = useState(checkBoxDataTemp);

const changeInput = (input) => {
  const { name, value } = input;
  // Why is the below code updating the state eventhough I am not using setCheckBoxData
  checkBoxData.find((item) => item.name === name).value = value;
};
```

please check the changeInput function.

EDIT: How to approach incase of data that should remain unchanged?

```js
let checkBoxDataTemp = [
  {
    name: "spam",
    label: "Spam", 
    value: false,
  },
  {
    name: "dangerousProduct",
    label: "Dangerous products",
    value: false,
  },
  {
    name: "sexuallyExplicit",
    label: "Sexually explicit"
    value: false,
  },
  {
    name: "other",
    label: "Other",
    value: false,
  },
];
```

Comment: Because you are mutating the array. Rule #1 in react - don't mutate state. Just because you are "allowed" to mutate, doesn't mean you should.

Comment: This "update" depends entirely on how you observe it.  Since you're not setting the state, as soon as the component re-renders your change will be lost.  But within the current render, any modifications you make to that state variable will be visible just like any other variable in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My doubt is why the state is updating when using a find method?

The `find` method isn't mutating the array, the assignment operator is:

```
checkBoxData.find((item) => item.name === name).value = value;

// is the same as
const someItem = checkBoxData.find((item) => item.name === name);
someItem.value = value // <-- this line
```

React `state` isn't special in this way, it's just a variable that you can mutate. But you absolutely never ever should update it without using the set method returned from `useState`.

EDIT: `changeInput` should look like this:

```
const changeInput = ({name,value}) => {
  setCheckboxData(data => data.map(item => item.name === name ? {...item,value} : item));
};
```

Comment: Is this approch a bad practice in react? Instead of mutating should I go with map followed by spread and using set method approach? Please tell me why this is a bad approach if it is so?

Comment: @milindsoorya: It's bad because it gives that render a false view of the current state, which could change at any time with a re-render.  If you need to update the state, use the setter from `useState` to update it.  As for the "right way" to do what you're currently doing... What exactly are you achieving currently?  What's the goal?  Right now all the example shows is mutating a state value for no reason, so the only answer is "don't do that".

Comment: @milindsoorya, see my edit.  Yes. This approach is not only a bad practice, but it results in bugs. Never mutate things in react (which is why I particularly hate mobx, at least in react - it works, but it encourages "magic" behaviour). state/props in react should be treated as immutable. It helps if you treat everything as immutable in react.

Comment: @adam, saw the edit. I really like the one-liner solution. But may I ask how you would approach it if there were some other key-value pairs other than name and value, and they should remain unchanged. I have added an example array as EDIT in the original question.

Comment: @milindsoorya I've edited again to suit your needs, so `value` is now the only element that gets changed.